# Placing Subfigures vertically

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I want to use subfigures to place three figures like this:

[image: one shape left two shapes right]

The following is the code I used:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{
        \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics{Fig2}
                \caption{Argumentation Framework $I$}
                \label{fig:afexampleI}
        \end{subfigure}
               }
        &
         \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.6\textwidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics{Fig3}
             \caption{Argumentation Framework $III$}
             \label{fig:afexampleIII}
         \end{subfigure} \\
        &
         \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.6\textwidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics{Fig4}
             \caption{Argumentation Framework $II$}
             \label{fig:afexampleII}
         \end{subfigure} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Argumentation Frameworks}\label{fig:afexample}
\end{figure}
```

However, this is the result:

[image]

P.S. I used `\hline` in order to better illustrate the figures, otherwise there should be no borders for the `tabular` environment used.

Comment: Here's another answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124537/is-the-following-layout-possible-with-the-subfigure-package/124544#124544, which supports hyperlinks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To have three independent figures with the desired layout, you can use `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=10cm]{image1}
  \caption{test figure one}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
  \caption{test figure two}
  \label{fig:test2}\par\vfill
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
  \caption{test figure three}
  \label{fig:test3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the three images as subfigures, you can simply replace `\caption` with `\subcaption` (from the `subcaption` package) in the previous code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=10cm]{image1}
  \subcaption{test figure one}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
  \subcaption{test figure two}
  \label{fig:test2}\par\vfill
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
  \subcaption{test figure three}
  \label{fig:test3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: @JLDiaz: would it be possible to achieve this effect using `tabular` and `subfigure`s?

Comment: @Ali no need for `tabular`; in my previous code, simply use `subfigure` instead of `minipage`; see my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I must confess that your solution using `minipage` was perfect. The updated solution leaves some white space above figure b. Thanks!

Comment: @Ali then I guess I will edit my answer showing both alternatives ;-)

Answer (score 9):

A `subfig` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newsavebox{\bigleftbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\sbox{\bigleftbox}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \subfloat[test figure one]
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=10cm]{image1}\label{fig:test1}}
  \end{minipage}%
}\usebox{\bigleftbox}%
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht\bigleftbox][s]{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[test figure two]
  {\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}\label{fig:test2}}

\vfill

\subfloat[test figure three]
  {\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}\label{fig:test3}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The big left subfigure is measured and typeset, so we can set the height of the right box to be exactly the same as the left box's.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could also use minipages if you don't want to use subfigures, so the result looks more like the example in the question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=10cm]{image1}
\caption{A Circle}
\label{fig:circle}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
\caption{test subfigure two}
\label{fig:test2}\par \medskip \vfill
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
\caption{test subfigure three}
\label{fig:test3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `tabular` + `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}[b]{p{5cm}}
 \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=10cm]{image1}\\     
 \subcaption{test figure one}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[b]{p{5cm}}
 \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{image2}\\  
 \subcaption{test figure 2}\\     
 \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{image1}\\     
 \subcaption{test figure three}
\end{tabular}
 \caption{figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]