# Is the following layout possible with the subfigure package?

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

Is it possible to achieve the following layout with the `subfigure` package (and any other package/command I don't know about):

```
############# ##############
#           # #            #
#  pic1     # #            #
#           # #      pic2  #
#           # #            #
############# #            #
              #            #
############# #            #
#           # #            #
#   pic3    # #            #
#           # #            #
#           # #            #
############# ##############
```

Each picture should have a subcaption.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: All right, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Instead of using the `subfigure` package I recommend switching to `caption` and `subcaption`. I am looking for an example, where i used this and will post it in a bit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`subfigure` is an obsolete package. One option cold be to use [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) and [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig); depending on the actual size of your figures, you might need to adjust some lengths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

As can be seen in Figure~\ref{fig:test}, we have the three subfigures~\ref{sfig:testa}, \ref{sfig:testb}, and \ref{sfig:testc}.
\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[7.8cm]{%
\begin{subfloatrow}
  \hsize0.7\hsize
  \vbox to 6.35cm{
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{small subfigure A}\label{sfig:testa}}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}\vss
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{small subfigure B}\label{sfig:testb}}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
  }
\end{subfloatrow}\hspace*{\columnsep}
\begin{subfloatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][]
    {\caption{A large subfigure}\label{sfig:testc}}
    {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}{\caption{three subfigures}\label{fig:test}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

EDITED so that this approach supports hyperlinking of subfigures.

Just replace the `\rules` with `\includegraphics` and put in your own captions.  The gap between subfigure and subcaption can be changed with an optional argument (e.g., `[5pt]`) to `\stackunder` in the definitions of `\capfiga`, `b`, and `c`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \def\figa{\rule{1in}{1.1in}}
  \def\figb{\rule{2in}{3.4in}}
  \def\figc{\rule{1in}{0.9in}}
  \def\capa{subfig a caption}
  \def\capb{subfig b caption}
  \def\capc{subfig c caption which may be longer}
  \savestack{\capfiga}{\subcaptionbox{\capa\label{fg:a}}{\figa}}
  \savestack{\capfigb}{\subcaptionbox{\capb\label{fg:b}}{\figb}}
  \savestack{\capfigc}{\subcaptionbox{\capc\label{fg:c}}{\figc}}
  \def\hgap{3ex}
  \stackon%
    [\heightof{\figb}-\heightof{\figc}-\heightof{\capfiga}-\depthof{\capfiga}]%
    {\capfigc}{\capfiga}\hspace{\hgap}\capfigb%
  \caption{This is my figure\label{fg:}}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
In figure \ref{fg:}, \ref{fg:a}, \ref{fg:b} and \ref{fg:c}...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly, for the current project, I need the hyperlinking to subfigures.

Comment: @user2586950  See revised version that hyperlinks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use it with the `caption` and `subcaption` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlength\heightfiga\newlength\heightcapa
\newlength\heightfigb\newlength\heightcapb
\newlength\heightfigc\newlength\heightcapc
\newlength\heightfig

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Look at that figure~\ref{fig}!

\lipsum[2]

And now look at figure~\ref{subfig2} in particular.

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}[b]
%Definition of lengths
\setlength\heightfiga{1.5cm}
\setlength\heightfigb{2.0cm}
\setlength\heightcapa{1\baselineskip}
\setlength\heightcapb{2\baselineskip}
%Do not change
\setlength\heightcapc{\heightcapa}
\setlength\heightfigc{\heightfiga+\heightfigb+\heightcapa}
\setlength\heightfig{\heightfigc+\heightcapc}

\begin{minipage}[b][\heightfig][t]{0.49\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[height=\heightfiga]{./graphics/dummy.eps}
\parbox[b][\heightcapa][t]{1\linewidth}{\subcaption{A caption}\label{subfig1}}
\includegraphics[height=\heightfigb]{./graphics/dummy.eps}
\parbox[b][\heightcapb][t]{1\linewidth}{\subcaption{Yet another caption}\label{subfig2}}

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b][\heightfig][t]{0.49\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=\heightfigc]{./graphics/dummy.eps}
\parbox[b][\heightcapc][t]{1.\linewidth}{\subcaption{Still a caption}\label{subfig3}}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{This is a figure}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]