# Looking for three images on top of each other with text underneath each

Tags: graphics, floats

I need to place three images on a page with text under each, and then one 'overall' caption for the figure. This code puts the images on top of each other but the text is to the left of the images, I need the text under each image. E.g. n = 10 steps should be the text directly under the first image.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \subfigure[$n = 10$ steps]{
        {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Raster/cw_10.png}
        \label{cw_10}
    }\\
    \subfigure[$n = 25$ steps]{
        {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Raster/cw_25.png}
        \label{cw_25}
    }\\
    \subfigure[$n = 50$ steps]{
        {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Raster/cw_50.png}
        \label{cw_50}
    }
    \caption{Classical Random Walk with various step sizes.}
    \label{TS}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`subfigure` is an obsolete package which shouldn't be used anymore. You can use [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead. Below, an example using `\subcaptionbox` from `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{$n = 10$ steps\label{cw_10}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Raster/cw_10.png}%
  }\par\medskip
\subcaptionbox{$n = 25$ steps\label{cw_25}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Raster/cw_25.png}%
  }\par\medskip        
\subcaptionbox{$n = 50$ steps\label{cw_50}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Raster/cw_50.png}%
  }
\caption{Classical Random Walk with various step sizes.}
\label{TS}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with `subfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[$n = 10$ steps\label{cw_10}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Raster/cw_10.png}%
  }\par
\subfloat[$n = 25$ steps\label{cw_25}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Raster/cw_25.png}%
  }\par        
\subfloat[$n = 50$ steps\label{cw_50}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Raster/cw_50.png}%
  }
\caption{Classical Random Walk with various step sizes.}
\label{TS}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Excellent! How can I add more horizontal spacing between the top of an image and the bottom of the text for each section?

Comment: @sonicboom in the first code of my updated answer, you can use something as `\par\medskip` instead of just `\par` to increase the vertical separation between subfigures. I am not sure if this is the distance you want to increase; if it's not, please let me know which one is.

Comment: It's perfect cheers. One thing, I have the label 'cw_10_25_50' for the overall figure (not TS as posted above). However, when I try and reference it using the text - In Figure ~\ref{fig:cw_10_25_50} we show the... - it comes up as Figure ?? we show the - when rendered with latex. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @sonicboom make sure the string used in `\ref` is *exactly* the same used in `\label`; so if `\label` is only `\label{cw_10_25_50}`, then you should use `\ref{cw_10_25_50}` (without the "fig:" prefix). Of course, if you want to use the prefix as in `\ref{fig:cw_10_25_50}`, then you should also include it in `\label`, as in `\label{fig:cw_10_25_50}`. Compile twice after doing the change. If the problem persists, the best thing to do will be to open a fresh new question.

Answer (score 5):

Gonzalo showed how to use `subcaption` package to solve the problem.  This also uses that package, but shows how stacks and `\subcaptionbox` can be used to increase the inter-image gap arbitrarily, using the `\setstackgap{S}{length}` command.

By using the `\subcaptionbox` variant of `subcaption`, arbitrary placement of the figures is possible, as also shown in this related answer:  [Is the following layout possible with the subfigure package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124537/is-the-following-layout-possible-with-the-subfigure-package/124544#124544)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \def\figa{\rule{1in}{1.1in}}
  \def\figb{\rule{1in}{1.5in}}
  \def\figc{\rule{1in}{0.9in}}
  \def\capa{subfig a caption}
  \def\capb{subfig b caption}
  \def\capc{subfig c caption which may be longer}
  \savestack{\capfiga}{\subcaptionbox{\capa\label{fg:a}}{\figa}}
  \savestack{\capfigb}{\subcaptionbox{\capb\label{fg:b}}{\figb}}
  \savestack{\capfigc}{\subcaptionbox{\capc\label{fg:c}}{\figc}}
  \setstackgap{S}{12pt}
  \Shortstack{\capfiga\\ \capfigb\\ \capfigc}%
  \caption{This is my figure\label{fg:}}
\end{figure}
In figure \ref{fg:}, \ref{fg:a}, \ref{fg:b} and \ref{fg:c}...
\end{document}
```

[image]