# how to do 3x1 subplots in one figure

Tags: subfloats

I need to do 3X1 subplots,  that is 3 row X 1 column, does someone here know how to do it?
Any help will be appreciated.
thanks in  advance

Comment: This question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169541/looking-for-three-images-on-top-of-each-other-with-text-underneath-each as well as this answer are related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170304/horizontal-alignment-of-subfigure-edges/170306#170306

Comment: Yo can also have a look at the section '1.1 Do you need this package?' in the [documentation](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) of [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig). The better approach depends on how you want the figures to be labeled or how many captions do you want.

Comment: A simple solution is to use a tabular.

Comment: Martinez, I need one caption for all three images but the three images must have a,b,c labeling so that I can refer to them in the caption. can you post your example?

Comment: John Kormylo, I would love to see the example with "tabular"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One tabular solution coming up:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}\\
A\\[3ex]% add a little extra space
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}\\
B\\[3ex]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-c}\\
C
\end{tabular}
\caption{Here are three figures.}%
\label{fig:cont}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular]

Why subfigure was developed in the first place is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig), [page 5](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf), slightly modified (added `\par`) to place them in three rows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfloat[][]{...figure code...}\par
\subfloat[][]{...figure code...}\par
\subfloat[][]{...figure code...}
\caption{Here are three figures.}%
\label{fig:cont}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```