# Positioning subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I would like to position three subfigures like this:

```
(a) (b)
(a) (c)
```

Figure (a) on the first roll and figures (b) and (c) on the second. Some light, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are `b` and `c` equally wide? What are the relative widths of `a` and `b` (or `c`)? Is `a` supposed to be as tall as `b` and `c` combined? Please clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is the following layout possible with the `subfigure` package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124537/5764)

Comment: Sorry. It was a dumb and bad formulated question.

Answer (score 0):

That it is. Thanks.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \center 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{F1.png}
      \caption{F1}
      \label{fig:f1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{F2.png}
          \caption{F2}
          \label{fig:f2}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{F3.png}
        \caption{F3}
        \label{fig:f3}
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{How to do it}
\label{fig:howtodoit}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I would think that `width=\textwidth` shouldn't be used for all the figures.

Comment: Your code seems needlessly complicated. For sure, don't create nested `subfigure` environments.

Comment: Yeah. I'll try to use the other solution. Thanks guys.