# add subcaptions in tabular

Tags: subcaption

I want to have subcaption to the subfigures and one caption below the figure. How can I add it to my code? Code below is without any captions.  The layout is:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}

  \includegraphics[width=2.5in,height=4in]{setupemb}


\end{adjustbox}
&
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}

  \includegraphics[width=2in,height=1.9in]{setup3}

  \\[2ex]
  \includegraphics[width=2in,height=1.9in]{metal2}
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124537/is-the-following-layout-possible-with-the-subfigure-package

Comment: Thank you. But none of the answers posted there uses tabular, and I can't make any of their codes work.

Comment: Captions like to be in minipages, but you can put a minipage inside a tabular.

Comment: Though it would be easier to just use `minipage`s. The `tabular` here is just egregious.

Comment: This is very similar to [your slightly earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321010/subfigures-position-multiple-rows). But now you have some code, which is much better, and are insisting on `tabular`, but I'm not clear why.