# Incompatibility problem of the packages subfig and subcaption

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I want have three subfigures in a special order. One on the right, two on the left. Therefor I found a snippet [here on StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66955/placing-subfigures-vertically). Alone the snippet works fine, you can check this by comment out the first figure-enviroment.

The problem is, that I have a lot of subfloats in my document and the packages subfig and subcaption are incompatible.

Is there a way to use normal subfloats and also get the 3-subfigure-example running?

Best, TomBoo!

**minimal example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
        \subfloat[test figure one \label{fig:1:test1}] {\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{image1}}
        \qquad %
        \subfloat[test figure two \label{fig:1:test2}] {\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{image1}}
    \caption{test figures}
  \label{fig:1:tests}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=10cm]{image1}
  \subcaption{test figure one}
  \label{fig:2:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
  \subcaption{test figure two}
  \label{fig:2:test2}\par\vfill
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
  \subcaption{test figure three}
  \label{fig:3:test3}
\end{minipage}
\caption{another test figures}
\label{fig:2:tests}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I have added a `subfig` based solution to the other question because it's better not having information scattered through different questions. If that new solution is good for you, please let us know so we can close this one as duplicate. Don't worry about this: this was indeed a good question.

Comment: The solution works perfectly fine! So can be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you say you are already using `subfig` extensive, I am assuming it would be a hassle to change all the `\subfloats`.  Therefore, you can use the `capt-of` package and set the `\captionsetup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space,font=small}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
        \subfloat[test figure one \label{fig:1:test1}] {\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{image1}}
        \qquad %
        \subfloat[test figure two \label{fig:1:test2}] {\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{image1}}
    \caption{test figures}
  \label{fig:1:tests}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=10cm]{image1}
  \captionof{subfigure}{test figure one}
  \label{fig:2:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c][11cm][t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
  \captionof{subfigure}{test figure two}
  \label{fig:2:test2}\par\vfill
  \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4.5cm]{image1}
  \captionof{subfigure}{test figure three}
  \label{fig:3:test3}
\end{minipage}
\caption{another test figures}
\label{fig:2:tests}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I need to figure out what I set to remove the `:` so I will update when I find it.  With Gonzalo Medina's suggestion, we can achieve the look of subfigures by having this line of code: `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space,font=small}`