# Label two tabular side by side

Tags: tables

I have 2 tabular side by side. How can I label them as (a) and (b) and can be referred from text using `\ref`.

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
a&b&c\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
d&e&f\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You can use the `subcaption` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use the [subcaption package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=en) for this purpose.

This package provides the `subtable` environment for the goal you wanted to achieve. Please read section 3 of the 
[package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) for details.

Please note how the `\subref` command has been used to refer to the subtables. If you want to refer using both main number and subnumber (e.g. 1(a)), you will want to use the `\ref` command. Format for all of these can be controlled. Please see the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf)
for this feature. Another [useful document is here](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/publishing/latex_captions).

Anyway, here is your code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!tbp]
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
        a&b&c\\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Table at left.}
      \label{tab:left}
    \end{center}
  \end{subtable}
  \quad
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
        d&e&f\\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Table at right.}
      \label{tab:right}
    \end{center}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{This contains two subtables.}
  \label{tab:main}
\end{table}

Please see the left~(\subref{tab:left}) and right~(\subref{tab:right})
tables.

\end{document}
```

And here is the output.

[image]

Comment: Is there any known incompatibility issue with `subcaption`?

Comment: There are a few reported issues, [1](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20579), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126985/incompatibility-problem-of-the-packages-subfig-and-subcaption/126988), and [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31906/subcaption-package-compatibility-issue). Unfortunately, I don't have any firsthand experiences with these.