# Subfigure out-of-order placement/numbering

Tags: floats, numbering

I have a figure illustrating a 3-step process, for which I use subfigures.
The desired output is something like this (excuse my paint skills):

[image: Desired output]

Now the placement of the subfigures/images is achievable [using minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66955/placing-subfigures-vertically) or multicolumn:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c][8cm][c]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{step1}
\subcaption{Step 1}
\label{fig:process11}

\includegraphics[height=3cm]{step3}
\subcaption{Step 3}
\label{fig:process13}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c][8cm][t]{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=7cm]{step2}
\subcaption{Step 2}
\label{fig:process12}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Process 1}
\label{fig:process1}
\end{figure}
```

However, that causes step 2 to have the c number and step 3 to have the b number. How can I fix the numbering?

Comment: Can you add a complete MWE (starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`)

Comment: Subcaption number follows orders of subcaptions in your code, there you have step 1, step 3 and step 2 and to them is accompanied a (step 1), b (step 3) and c (step 2). Reorder  order of code acordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust them manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c][8cm][c]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\vspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{step1}
\subcaption{Step 1}
\label{fig:process11}

\addtocounter{subfigure}{1}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{step1}
\subcaption{Step 3}
\label{fig:process13}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c][8cm][t]{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=7cm]{step2}
\addtocounter{subfigure}{-2}
\subcaption{Step 2}
\label{fig:process12}

\end{minipage}
\caption{Process 1}
\label{fig:process1}
\end{figure}

Step 3 (Figure~\ref{fig:process13}).
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can load them into `\savebox`es in the correct order, then arrange the boxes in any order.

[image: saveboxes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newsavebox{\tempboxb}
\newsavebox{\tempboxc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
% firat step
\savebox{\tempboxa}{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{Step 1}
\label{fig:process11}
\end{minipage}}
% second step
\savebox{\tempboxb}{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering% redundant in this case
\includegraphics[height=7cm,width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\subcaption{Step 2}
\label{fig:process12}
\end{minipage}}
% third step
\savebox{\tempboxc}{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-c}
\subcaption{Step 3}
\label{fig:process13}
\end{minipage}}
% arrange boxes
\parbox[b][\ht\tempboxb][s]{0.5\textwidth}{%
\usebox{\tempboxa}
\vfill
\usebox{\tempboxc}}%
\usebox{\tempboxb}
\caption{Process 1}
\label{fig:process1}
\end{figure}

Step 1 (Figure~\ref{fig:process11}).\par
Step 2 (Figure~\ref{fig:process12}).\par
Step 3 (Figure~\ref{fig:process13}).
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to put graphic in table with `multirow` in second column. Than (after manual adjusting of images positions) you can obtain:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.48\textwidth}p{0.48\textwidth}}
\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
\captionof{subfigure}{Step 1}
\label{fig:process11}
&   \multirow{2}{\hsize}[32mm]{
    \includegraphics[height=7cm,width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
     \captionof{subfigure}{Step 2}
    \label{fig:process12} 
                        }
    \\[-4mm]
\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=\hsize]{example-image-c}
\captionof{subfigure}{Step 3}
\label{fig:process11}
    &    
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Process 1}
\label{fig:process1}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

If your figure occupy less than text width, you reduce witdh of columns accordingly and after `\begin{figure}` add `\centering}`.