# Renumbering figure in different order

Tags: graphics

If I define three figures like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfigure} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \subfigure[A]{\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{pictures/a.jpg}}\hfill
 \subfigure[B]{\includegraphics[width=.237\textwidth]{pictures/b.jpg}}
 \caption{Caption 1}\label{AA}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \subfigure[C]{\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{pictures/c.jpg}}\hfill
 \subfigure[D]{\includegraphics[width=.237\textwidth]{pictures/d.jpg}}
 \caption{Caption 2}\label{BB}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \subfigure[E]{\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{pictures/e.jpg}}\hfill
 \subfigure[F]{\includegraphics[width=.237\textwidth]{pictures/f.jpg}}
 \caption{Caption 3}\label{cc}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

So the result can be showing 3 images one by one, but I want to set the number of the figure with label AA as 3, and the one with label BB as 1. The one with label CC as 2.

You might recommend changing the order in code, but I do not want to do in that way. How can I do that by LaTeX?

Comment: Please can you edit your code and could put a complete and compilable MWE with all your package?

Comment: I see you edited your question and added some `\usepackage` commands. However, (1) they should not be inside `\begin{document}...\end{document}` and (2) please add the `\documentclass`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269301/subfigure-out-of-order-placement-numbering/269339?r=SearchResults&s=1|43.4295#269339

Comment: Your renumbering of the figures will look very odd to any reader of your work. They expect the figures to be numbered in the order that they appear in the document. As an extreme example what if you had 100 figures and labelled the first as 100 and the last as 1. How would your reader know where to look if you referenced them in your text?

Answer (score 1):

By adding the option: `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` you can change the current figure order in your document. Try `\addtocounter{figure}{2}` before figure AA, so the current fig. number will be 2. After inserting Figure AA, try `\addtocounter{figure}{-3}` and ....

```
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{XXXX}
 \centering
   \caption{Continued}
   \label{fig:XX}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
```