# Arranging 2 x 3 figures using subfigure with top to bottom priority instead of left to right priority

Tags: subfloats

I am very satisfied with the result from subfigure package so far.
But now I need to make the sequence with top to bottom priority.

```
a d
b e
c f
```

How to do it?

this code produce neat error free result but the subfigures are arranged from left to right first.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfigure[]
{\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{figures/placeholder} 
\label{fig:placeholder1}}
\subfigure[]
{\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{figures/placeholder} 
\label{fig:placeholder2}}
\subfigure[]
{\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{figures/placeholder} 
\label{fig:placeholder3}}
\subfigure[]
{\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{figures/placeholder} 
\label{fig:placeholder4}}
\subfigure[]
{\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{figures/placeholder} 
\label{fig:placeholder5}}
\subfigure[]
{\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{figures/placeholder} 
\label{fig:placeholder6}}
\caption[faafasfasf.]{affffafasfsfsfssfs.}
\label{fig:ffsfsfssff}
\end{figure}
```

result
[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269301/subfigure-out-of-order-placement-numbering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a minipage like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \subfigure[Figure A]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}}
        \subfigure[Figure B]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}}
        \subfigure[Figure C]{\label{fig:c}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \subfigure[Figure D]{\label{fig:d}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}}
        \subfigure[Figure E]{\label{fig:e}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}}
        \subfigure[Figure F]{\label{fig:f}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{my caption}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it works nicely. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Or with `multicol`. Commented lines are for `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
%           \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
%               \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-a}
%               \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:a}
%           \end{subfigure}
%           \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
%               \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
%               \caption{B subfigure}\label{fig:b}
%           \end{subfigure}
%           \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
%               \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-c}
%               \caption{C subfigure}\label{fig:c}
%           \end{subfigure}
%           \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
%               \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-a}
%               \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:a}
%           \end{subfigure}
%           \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
%               \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-b}
%               \caption{B subfigure}\label{fig:b}
%           \end{subfigure}
%           \begin{subfigure}[b]{\linewidth}
%               \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{example-image-c}
%               \caption{C subfigure}\label{fig:c}
%           \end{subfigure}
            \subfigure[Figure A]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
            \subfigure[Figure B]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
            \subfigure[Figure C]{\label{fig:c}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
            \subfigure[Figure D]{\label{fig:d}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
            \subfigure[Figure E]{\label{fig:e}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
            \subfigure[Figure F]{\label{fig:f}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
        \end{multicols}
    \caption{my caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```