# Placing subfig vertically

Tags: subfloats, subfig, sidesubfloat

There is a beautiful [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66955/placing-subfigures-vertically) where it is explained more or less what I would like to do.

Actually, I am not using subfigure, but `\usepackage{subfig}`. Therefore, I've tried to implement the example with the `subfig` solution. My entire document is using `subfig`, I would not change to subfigure now.

Here is the code I am using:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\sbox{\bigleftbox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \subfloat[Image 1]
        {\includegraphics[height=5cm]%
        {images1}%
        \label{image1}}
    \end{minipage}%
}\usebox{\bigleftbox}%
    \begin{minipage}[b][\ht\bigleftbox][s]{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Image 2]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]%
        {images2}%
        \label{image2}}
    \vfill
    \subfloat[Image 3]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]%
        {images3}%
        \label{image3}}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{%
    Figure}
\label{figure}
\end{figure}
```

In the attached picture I can see the result and it is not glorious. 
I would not like to change the change the size of the picture. The size shall remain the same. The problem is that 1) the left picture is not vertically centered with respect with the two other images, 2) the caption of the figure is not at the bottom of the last picture, and 3) the title of the next section is entering the figure.

How is it possible to solve all these problems using `subfig` and not `subfigure`?

I would be very thankful for your help.

[image: example of obtained result]

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Using `subfig` and insisting in it in combination of the `savebox` an and the `minipages` makes the result and your demand really strange. If you really are open to use `minipages`, than the `subcaption` package should be enough for your approach and the `subfig` could not help somehere.

Comment: In my above comment, I had understood that you expect the caption of the left figure aligned with the caption of the lower right figure and thus could not find a way that `subfig` package could be used for it (doesn't really use it often but if this was the case the `subcaption` package and the `minipages` should be enough). Commenting just to explain the above comment and to suggest to to have a look (whenever you find time) at the `subcaption` package that is better cooperating with `minipages` and such cases as this one.

Comment: @koleygr Hi. Thanks a lot for the feedback. My entire document uses 'subfig'. Changing everything to 'subcaption' might take a bit of time. I will try to use 'subcaption' for my next documents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is different, as you don't have to measure anything.

In order to align the two parts at the top, you can use `\raisebox{-\height}{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering

\raisebox{-\height}{%
  \subfloat[Image 1]{%
     \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-9x16}%
     \label{image1}%
  }%
}\qquad
\raisebox{-\height}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \subfloat[Image 2]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}%
    \label{image2}%
  } \\
  \subfloat[Image 3]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}%
    \label{image3}%
  }
  \end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Figure}
\label{figure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to vertically center the left image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \subfloat[Image 1]{%
     \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-9x16}%
     \label{image1}%
  }%
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \subfloat[Image 2]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}%
    \label{image2}%
  } \\
  \subfloat[Image 3]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}%
    \label{image3}%
  }
\end{tabular}

\caption{Figure}
\label{figure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the tabular solution solved my problem. It makes the result I would like. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

see if the following example can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[export, demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\newsavebox\bigleftbox

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \multirow[t]{2}{=}{\subfloat[Image 1 \label{image1}]%
                    {\includegraphics[height=5cm, valign=t]{images1}}%
                    }
    &   \subfloat[Image 2 \label{image2}]%
                    {\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr2.5 cm-\baselineskip, valign=t]{images1}} \\
    &   \subfloat[Image 3 \label{image3}]%
                    {\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr2.5 cm-\baselineskip, valign=b]{images1}} \\
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Figure}
\label{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variant using minipages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
    \subfloat[Image 1]{%
       \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-9x16}%
       \label{image1}%
    }
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
   \subfloat[Image 2]{%
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}%
      \label{image2}%
    }

   \subfloat[Image 3]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}%
    \label{image3}%
  }
  \end{minipage}
\caption{Figure}
\label{figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```