# Placing 3 figures in Latex in 2 columns

Tags: two-column, subfig

I want to display 3 figures as shown on the picture: 2 in the same column and the third one on the right column. My document isnt in columns.

I tried things with subfigure, but i only achieved to place 2 figures in a same row[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please show us, what you try so far. DO this figures has (sub)captions)? Try to insert them in two consecutive  `minipage`s.

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66955/placing-subfigures-vertically?noredirect=1&lq=1 helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]\\
        \begin{table}[h!]
        \caption{Table with 3 graphs}
        
        \begin{tabular}{l l}

            \parbox{2in}{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=1in]{image-a}\\ \includegraphics[width=2in,height=1in]{image-b}} &\parbox{2in}{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{image-c}}\\

        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you want captions below each subfigure consider this modified code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]\\
        \begin{table}[h!]
            \begin{center}
                \caption{Table with 3 graphs}
                \begin{tabular}{l l}
                    \parbox{2in}{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=1in]{image-a}\\ (a) sinus graph\\ \includegraphics[width=2in,height=1in]{image-b}\\(b)cosinus graph} &\parbox{2in}{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=2.2in]{image-c}\\ (c) tangent graph}\\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{center}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

and his output:

[image]